# Changing a registry value with C++? (system command failed)

Tags: c++, registry, command, system, editing

Well, I have been told time and time again that system command is bad, but I need to change a registry value and my forte is batch so I have a commmand in mind that does it:

```
system("REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D "C:\background.bmp"");
system("REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V WallpaperStyle /T REG_SZ /F /D 0");
system("REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V TileWallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D 2");
system("%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters");
```

However, using this makes Visual C++ 2010 Express highlight HKCU and the slash betweeen Panel and Desktop as an error and does not allow me to compile or debug my program. I don't want to use the system command so I was wondering how to use a C++ to preform the same registry command?
I DON'T UNDERSTAND WIN32 REGISTRY API???

And is it ok to use the system command for this

```
system("%SystemRoot%\System32\RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters");
```

because I don't know if C++ can preform the same task without it, and if it can how???

Sorry, I know it's a big question but if possible could you please include code, I am just beginning and none of the other forums make any sense and I have been looking for atlease three hours (I am not stupid with computers either)!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extra work is needed to write string literals that contain special characters.  For example, in your code, the `"` after `ADD` is the end of the string.

You need to put a backspace before each special character (includes quotes and backspaces) to make sure they are put into the string instead of being processed by the compiler.  This is called *escaping*.

The result will look like this:

```
system("REG ADD \"HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" /V Wallpaper /T REG_SZ /F /D \"C:\\background.bmp\"");
```

Using the Registry API is a better option for your task, of course, but you also needed to know how to write string literals properly.

Comment: Yes, with the Registry API.  MSDN is full of examples.  Here's one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

Please use the [Win32 Registry API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!!!

Comment: I have already tried, it made no sense to me? I am just beginning and some of the stuff still hasn't clicked yet!!!!Can you explain how it works and please give an example!

Comment: @linuxuser27: I think the exclamatory tail is deliberate irony.

Comment: @user1715942: Are you taking the piss?

Comment: I get excitable sometimes.  No offense intended.  There is lots of sample code out there, if you just search for "C++ code to modify windows registry key".  You even get [results on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247093/edit-registry-values)

Comment: @MarceloCantos turns out I was _not_ taking the piss, I wrote this when I was like 13 and just found it again (what a laugh). I also didn't understand what deliberate irony meant, but thankfully I now understand how to escape string literals, and why system commands really never should be used. Overall, I can recommend not learning batch as your first programming language.(and even though this sounds like satire I promise it's not).

Comment: Ahh I see the confusion and subsequent exasperation.  Never considered batch to be a programming language - it's just a dumbed down shell script.  In the late 80s we all took this for granted, and anyone who wanted to code on PC would start with actual languages like BASIC, Pascal, C or Assembly.  And generally we just learned by reading code instead of asking it to be fed to us ;)  Hope you're enjoying your C++ journey!